# How to design db for holding Dominion cards?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'd like to store some information about games of the card game Dominion. You don't need to know much about this game, except that:

- There are around 200 unique cards
- Each game includes only ten of these cards, or on occasion eleven

I'll be tracking lots more about each game (who played, who won, etc), but what I'm having trouble with is working with the "supply" (the ten included cards for this game).

I'm thinking I want three tables, something like `card_name`, `supply`, and `game`:

```
 card_name            supply                        game                                      

 id | name        supply | card     game | supply | player1 | player2 | ... 
----+---------   --------+------   ------+--------+---------+---------+-----
  1 | Village          1 | 1         301 |      1 |  'Mike' |  'Tina' | ... 
  2 | Moat             1 | 3      
  3 | Witch            1 | 200    
... | ...            ... | ...    
200 | Armory
```

I think this is a reasonable way to represent "Mike and Tina played a game which contained Village, Witch, Armory, and some other cards I didn't bother typing into this example". Given this structure (or some other one, if you think mine is no good), I'd like to run queries like "which games had Witch and Village, but not Moat?" That is, I want to specify some arbitrary number of "these X cards included, these Y cards excluded" and search the `game` table for games satisfying the criteria.

I think this is a classic one-to-many relation, where a supply has multiple cards, but I don't understand the right way to search for a supply by multiple cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data structure is reasonable.  I might suggest that you would want a `game_users` table as well, so the users are not listed in separate columns.  This would be particularly important if games had different numbers of users.  However, this aspect is not relevant to your question.

You want to solve "set-within-sets" subqueries.  Your structure is useful and the `supply` table provides the basic information needed for this.

So, a query to get the appropriate "supply" records for "Witch", "Village", and not "Moat" would look like:

```
select supplyid
from supplies s join
     cards c
     on s.cardid = c.cardid
group by supplyid
having sum(case when cardname = 'Witch' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cardname = 'Village' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cardname = 'Moat' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

First note that I changed the name, so the id columns contain the word "id" and the table names are in plural.

Each condition in the having clause is representing one condition on the cards.  You can tweak this to get the game information by joining in `games`:

```
select g.gameid
from supplies s join
     cards c
     on s.cardid = c.cardid join
     games g
     on g.supplyid = s.gameid
group by g.gameid
having sum(case when cardname = 'Witch' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cardname = 'Village' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when cardname = 'Moat' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: This `having sum` solution seems like it necessitates a linear scan of all games, right? I have a small enough dataset that this may be acceptable, but I was hoping for something that can take advantage of indexes.

Comment: @amalloy . . . Postgres isn't MySQL.  It actually implements fairly reasonable aggregation algorithms.  In this case, you could include a `where cardname in ('Witch', 'Village', 'Moat')` and an index could be used for that to reduce the search space.

Comment: Postgres didn't like it when I wrote `sum(cardname = 'Witch')`, because `sum` wants a number rather than a boolean. I had to add a cast to int; should that be edited into your answer, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @amalloy . . . Could the question have been tagged with MySQL?  I originally used MySQL syntax and would normally only do that if the question were so tagged.  I fixed the syntax to use the ANSI standard `case` which works in Postgres (and many other databases).